# FileMaker alternate

Tags: software-recommendation

This question has been asked and answered in the distant past.  And those answers don't seem relevant in 2016.  I'm looking for a simple, low cost or free database app that I can use to track my books and other genealogy info.  I'm an old dog and don't want to learn any new tricks so any app needs to be very simple.  PS: this is my first foray into this website.

Comment: Please specify more about your needs. How is FileMaker not meeting those needs?

Comment: What I found on the internet was too expensive and seemed to be too complex for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice - Base deserves a look. Free

https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/